# Android: Receive Push Notification when the App isn't running

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I am looking to implement push notifications in my app.  I have already sent notifications from inside the application's context, but I want the user to receive notifications when the app isn't running.  For example, you receive a Twitter or Facebook notification when you have a new message, but the Facebook app isn't open or running.  I will be reading data from a server.  When the server sends out a message, I want the user to get the notification, whether the app is open or not.  I have looked at `Service` but couldn't find anything promising.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) in your app. This works by sending push notifications through the Google Services, which are almost always active on an Android device. These services will then broadcast the notification to your app, and you can handle and use the data once you have received it from the Google Services.

Comment: GCM doesn't seem to work on my device, even though it's higher than 2.2.  The method `checkDevice()` throws an exception, meaning my device isn't supported.  Is there a way to achieve the same functionality from a different method.